# Joint probability of three events, when two of them are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My main question is:
if `B` and `C` are independent, then can we conclude the following:
`P(A|B,C)=P(A|B)*P(A|C)`?
Simply it can be seen that the conclusion is true if and only if:
`A and B independent => P(A,B,C)=P(A,B)*P(A,C)` 
Now I'm wondering whether it's true or not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is a counterexample. Toss a fair coin twice. Let $B$ be the event the first toss gives head, let $C$ be the event the second toss gives head. Let $A$ be the event both give head.

Then $\Pr(A|B,C)=1$ while $\Pr(A|B)\Pr(A|C)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: You are welcome. Intuition about conditional probabilities is not always reliable.

Comment: Exactly! And I like to reach that kind of insight through which you came up with this counterexample.